# Como usar UISearchBar com dados vindos do Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uisearchbar

Estou tentando filtrar o nome das células de uma tabela, carregada com dados vindos do Core Data, porém estou tendo um crash.

Estou usando o seguinte código para filtrar o titulo das células:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

    if (searchText.length == 0) {

        // Ajustando valor da flah booleana
        isFiltrado = NO;
    }else{

        // Ajustando valor da flah booleana
        isFiltrado = YES;

        // Alloc e inicia nosso dadosFiltrados
        dadosFiltrados = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];

        //Fast enumeration
        for (NSDictionary* nomeAtividade in arrayAtividadeLocal) {

            NSRange rangeNomeAtividade = [[nomeAtividade objectForKey:@"atividade" ]rangeOfString:searchText];

            if (rangeNomeAtividade.location != NSNotFound) {
                [dadosFiltrados addObject: nomeAtividade];
            }
        }
    }
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro do Xcode:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject
>   objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao que parece de acordo com o erro, em `arrayAtividadeLocal` você tem um vetor de objetos do *Core Data*, é isso mesmo?

Assim sendo, você precisa fazer a iteração considerando esse objeto e não um *NSDictionary*, por exemplo:

```
for (AtividadeLocal *objAtividade in arrayAtividadeLocal) {
    NSString *nomeAtividade = [objAtividade atividade]; // Objeto e propriedade
    NSRange rangeNomeAtividade = [nomeAtividade rangeOfString:searchText];

    if (rangeNomeAtividade.location != NSNotFound) {
        [dadosFiltrados addObject:objAtividade];
    }
}
```

Comment: eu achei o erro mas depois surgiu outro de lógica:

 O 1º eu resolvi pegando os titulos dos objetos que vinham do core data e passando para um NSMutableArray>

Porem agora, ele até acha o objeto na busca porem ele sempre aponta para o primeiro na pilha do array :/

Comment: O mais engraçado que agora ele está idêntico ao tutorial que eu fiz, e funciona normalmente, mas na implementação do projeto esta com esse problema de apresentar o dado correto na busca :/

Comment: Você aumentou o processo com essa nova iteração para ter só os nomes. Dá pra fazer tudo no mesmo *array*. Enfim, sobre o outro problema, precisa saber como foi feita a implementação.

Comment: Fala comigo pelo skype ai vou poder te mostrar melhor

Comment: Achei o problema, estava no cellForRowAtIndexPath, eu ainda estava alimentando as células com os dados originais, e não com os dados filtrados :D

Comment: Ah sim, pelo método que você está usando, não imaginei que você estava utilizando o `UISearchDisplay`. Para ele sim, você tem uma tabela com dados diferentes só com o resultado da busca.

Comment: Vc entende algo sobre APNS? Preciso somente criar um sistema de push notification e meu app estará finalizado... mas não quero usar nenhum serviço de terceiros, ja´ possuo um web service... eu postei a questão no stackoverflow, mas se quiser podemos conversar pelo skype, se vc puder tbm